# Cookies are not setting in some clients

Tags: java, session, cookies

I am facing a slightly weird problem. I am setting a cookie in my Java Servlet, and accessing it later. This works when I am accessing my webapp from `certain machines`. However, from others, it is not working.

On further analysis, I found that the cookie is not setting in some browsers. However, in the same browser, `another cookie` I am setting in another part of my webapp, is `successfully stored`. Anyone else has faced similar issues before?

Details : 
OS : Windows XP
Browser : Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13

Code :

```
tempCookie = new Cookie("CN.checkCookie", "try this!!!");
tempCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
response.addCookie(tempCookie);
```

*Another observation* :
When the cookie setting fails, I have also seen that variables stored previously in the session variable, are also lost.

Cheers,
Rohitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like privacy configuration in your browser. Check it. As far as I remember your can configure privacy in browsers per URL. This may explain this strange behavior.

Additionally I'd recommend you to call setDomain() and setPath() explicitly.

Comment: It worked on explicitly adding path and domain! Thank you so much, Alex. However, I still can't figure out, why the session is getting lost...